# How to set the TMPDIR environment variable to another directory?

Tags: shell, unix

I'M triyng to compile ffmpeg and there is a problem with tmp dir because is mounted with noexec:

> ./configure --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --disable-mmx
>   --enable-shared Unable to create and execute files in /tmp.  Set the TMPDIR environment variable to another directory and make sure that it
>   is not mounted noexec. Sanity test failed.
>
> If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the
>   latest version from SVN.  If the latest version fails, report the
>   problem to the ffmpeg-user@mplayerhq.hu mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on
>   irc.freenode.net. Include the log file "config.err" produced by
>   configure as this will help solving the problem.

How to set the TMPDIR environment variable to another directory?

Comment: My case:
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib -ldl" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --pkg-config-flags="--static" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
Unable to create and execute files in /tmp.  Set the TMPDIR environment
variable to another directory and make sure that it is not mounted noexec.
Sanity test failed.

Answer (score 25):

I was able to get it done using that code bellow:

```
$ export TMPDIR=~/tmp-ffmpeg

$ mkdir $TMPDIR

$ ./configure \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-version3 \
  --enable-shared \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-postproc \
  --enable-libfaac \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
  --enable-libopencore-amrwb \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libxvid \
  --enable-x11grab \
  --extra-cflags="-I/usr/local/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L/usr/local/lib"

$ make
$ make install
$ rm -rf $TMPDIR
$ unset TMPDIR
```

There is also `mktemp(1)` command. So that you can set TMPDIR as follows:

```
$ TMPDIR="$(mktemp -d -q ~/tmp/tmp.XXXXX)"
$ echo $TMPDIR
/home/marcelo/tmp/tmp.I8V9H
```

This should work for GNU coreutils as well as for BSD (macOs, FreeBSD, etc). Also note, you not need to export TMPDIR and then unset it. Instead try to pass variable directly to configure:

```
$ TMPDIR="/foo/bar/baz" ./configure ...
```

Hope it helps somebody else ;-)

Comment: Try `unset TMPDIR` instead of `export TMPDIR=`. An empty string is not a good default for TMPDIR.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
TMPDIR=/some/other/dir ./configure --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --disable-mmx --enable-shared
```

If you'd like to execute several commands with the new TMPDIR, and assuming you're using bash as a shell, `export` it first.

```
export TMPDIR=/some/other/dir
./configure --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --disable-mmx --enable-shared
...
```

Comment: `export` is POSIX and is not bash-specific. Your examples should work in any POSIX shell.