# Winerror8 while installing Django 3.2

Tags: python, django

I was trying to install Django 3.2 using pip.The installation was completed 50% but suddenly an error popup showing [winerror8] not enough storage can someone help me with this.

Comment: What do you need help with? Is the error unclear?

Comment: @dfundako what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

I think your temp directory might not have enough space, the pip installation uses the temp directory as the storage while the installation
1- one solution is to clean up /temp space
2- or change the /temp refer this -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11697248/9630323